# Migrating Oracle Table partially to SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, migration, transfer

I am new to SSIS and I will jump right in:

Requirements:

- Migrate table data from Oracle to SQL Server using SSIS
- One of these tables has 50+ million rows on the source, only migrate X number of rows based on a a date column, no staging tables allowed

What has been accomplished:

Data flow has been created, currently all rows and all tables migrate without issue.

What remains to be done:

This one particular table needs to be partially imported. How can I do this keeping the requirement in mind. The requirements are firm, SSIS a must and no staging tables are permitted.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your Data Flow, I would edit the Data Source object for that particular table.  There I would design a SQL statement e.g.

SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE mytable.datex >= to_date ( '2014-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd' )

Comment: No staging tables permitted? Sounds like you have a misguided architect in the mix there.

Comment: Unforunatley, it is not my decision to make and I ended up doing something similar to what was suggested by Mike H.

Comment: @ElectricLlama - on the contrary this scenario is an ideal use of  SSIS - more efficient in design (no staging tables to maintain) and execution (roughly half the I/O of a staging table solution).

Comment: I agree it is an ideal use of SSIS. However I believe the design constraint 'no staging tables allowed' is often a misguided one. Certainly for this question they are not required.